# Getting a not found error when using split with dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with *spark* and *scala*. I have the below code that works fine on *spark-shell*, but when I try to move it over to *Intelij* it throws on error, stating unable to find `split`.

What am I missing, what do I need to import for `split` to work

```
var outputDF = inputDF.withColumn(srcColumn, 
split(inputDF.col(srcColumn),splitBy).getItem(selectIndex))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably missing this import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

(which is provided automatically in a Spark shell)